# How can I view and edit specific aspects of playerdata from my Minecraft server?

Tags: java, ftp, minecraft

I'm trying to switch my server over to a new mod pack, while keeping player inventory and a few other aspects of playerdata. I want to be able to transfer a player from one server to another, while resetting their location data. Are there specific tools I use to view and edit these values, and which files specifically under the playerdata folder would contain them?

To clarify, When their location data is reset I would like them to go to spawn. If it wont default, then entering a value will be a little more work, but sufficient.

I've already transferred the playerdata into my new world file. I plan in switching the server every-so-often and allowing these item transfers quite abit, so I need to know for the future how to solve this without requiring all of my players to be coordinated during the transfer.

Comment: can't you manually teleport them to the new location? Or maybe use bukkit and use a plugin for that?

Comment: @Kerooker I can teleport them, only if they're online at the same time as me. An issue already with this is that a player spawned inside stone on the new map, and nearly lost his inventory from the transfer. And Bukkit is a no-go due to my server being forge-based. Bukkit is currently incompatible with forge, and the alternative Sponge program has given me endless problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minecraft 1.7.6 or newer (UUID)**

On Minecraft 1.7.6 and above, Mojang uses a new UUID format. Use a UUID lookup tool, like http://minecraft-techworld.com/uuid-lookup-tool to determine the UUID of the player you wish to reset.

1. Make sure that the player you wish to reset is logged out of the server.
2. Use FileZilla to connect to the server FTP.
3. On the remote site, open the game folder.
4. Open the world folder. It is usually world, unless you have changed it.
5. Open playerdata.
6. Simple: Delete, or download/rename and then delete, uuid.dat. Replace uuid with the UUID that you looked up.
7. Advanced: Instead of deleting uuid.dat, download it to a location on your computer such as your desktop where you can easily find it.
8. From NBTExplorer, press the "Open NBT Data Source" button that looks like a folder.
9. Navigate to where you saved the uuid.dat file, select it, and press open.
10. Scroll down untill you find the tag labeled "Pos" with 3 entries and press  the "+" symbol next to it. These are the data tags that store where a player is in game.
11. Double click on the tags one at a time and change their values. The tags aren't labelled, but they are X, Y, Z in that order. Y is height. Be careful what you set these numbers to as you can cause a player to spawn in the ground. I suggest setting their value to your world's spawn or a known safe coordinate location.
12. Upload the uuid.dat back to your server in the same place you got it. Overwrite or delete the original one. Make sure that the player in question is not online at the time or it won't work.

[SOURCE](http://www.akliz.net/manage/knowledgebase/48/How-to-Reset-a-Playerandsharp039s-Location-and-Inventory-on-a-Minecraft-Server.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin,
which can get all offlinePlayers() and then use a for to iterate the array to set the spawnlocation to the new one on the other pack.

This you can trigger with a cmd which you code for it.